# MPI, If using non-blocking i_send or i_recv, does it matter which one goes first if there is a wait at the end?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, nonblocking

If I call `MPI_isend` then `MPI_irecv` or do a irecv first then a isend, with a wait at the end? does it matter which order?

Answer (score 0):

> if i MPI_isend then MPI_irecv or do a irecv first then a isend, with a
> wait at the end? does it matter which order?

[MPI_Irecv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Irecv.html) and [MPI_Isend](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Isend.html) are nonblocking communication routines, therefore one needs to use the [MPI_Wait](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Wait.html) (or use [MPI_Test](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html) to test for the completion of the request) to ensure that the message is completed, and that the data in the send/receive buffer can be again **safely** manipulated.

The nonblocking here means one does not wait for the data to be read and sent; rather the data is **immediately made available to be read and sent.** That does not imply, however, that the data is immediately sent. If it were, there would not be a need to call MPI_Wait.

Quoting [@hristo-away-iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/) on [source](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/when-is-mpi-wait-necessary-for-non-blocking-calls)

> You must always wait on or test nonblocking operations if you'd like
> your programs to be standard compliant and hence portable. **The
> standard allows the implementation to postpone the actual data
> transmission until the wait/test call.** Some MPI operations (other than
> wait/test) progress non-blocking operations but one should not rely on
> this behaviour.

and

> MPI_Isend does not necessarily progress in the background but only
> when the MPI implementation is given the chance to progress it.
> MPI_Wait progresses the operation and guarantees its completion. Some
> MPI implementations can progress operations in the background using
> progression threads. Some cannot. It is implementation-dependent and
> one should never rely on one or another specific behaviour.

Comment: This does not address the question

Comment: it does not matter the order if one has a wait in the end